# Changing GoogleMaps map type

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, maps

I have a simple code that presents a map with few different locations, which change depending on clicked row in a table. Map shows as espected, but when I try to change the type to, let's say, Satellite, the map just fades out, but the Google logo is still there, so are the markers I have set on the map. I can't figure out what im missing here. Here's some code.

```
@IBOutlet var myMapView: UIView!
var mapView: GMSMapView?
var currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var marker = GMSMarker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    kreirajMapu() -  creates the map
}

func kreirajMapu() { 
    currentLocation = magacin[red].artikal[redZaMapu].lokacija

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (currentLocation?.latitude)!, longitude: (currentLocation?.longitude)!, zoom: 15)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: myMapView.bounds, camera: camera)
    mapView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView?.settings.compassButton = true
    mapView?.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView?.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true)
    myMapView.addSubview(mapView!)
}

func moveCamera() {

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(2, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)

    mapView?.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: magacin[red].artikal[redZaMapu].lokacija, zoom: magacin[red].artikal[redZaMapu].zoom))
    mapView?.animate(toViewingAngle: 45)

    CATransaction.commit()
    marker = GMSMarker(position: magacin[red].artikal[redZaMapu].lokacija)
    marker.title = magacin[red].artikal[redZaMapu].naziv
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.snippet  = "This is where \(magacin[red].artikal[redZaMapu].naziv)'s live"
    marker.map = mapView
}

@IBAction func mapType(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Map Types", message: "Select map type:", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Normal", style: .default, handler: {_ in
        self.mapView?.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Hybrid", style: .default, handler: {_ in
        self.mapView?.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Satellite", style: .default, handler: {_ in
        self.mapView?.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Terrain", style: .default, handler: {_ in
        self.mapView?.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was, make sure to enable GoogleMap API on google.developer for the app you are trying to use it on. Thanks for everybody's contribution :/